gdiScaling: can be disable for a specific child window?
I have enabled the gdiScaling option to my MFC C++ application using manifest.
However I have a specific internal child window drawn with GDI that has some glitches and performance issues.
Can the "advanced" gdiScaling can be disabled for this specific internal child window only, and restore the "classic" low-quality rescale (but keep the rest properly rescaled)?
PS: gdiScalign is enabled as described in https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/05/19/improving-high-dpi-experience-gdi-based-desktop-apps/

no, the DPI scaling is applied to the entire toplevel window.

the window is not child of the toplevel window, it is child of another dialog

You could try to use SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior and SetDialogControlDpiChangeBehavior to opt a specific window in a dialog (or the entire dialog itself) out of DPI scaling functionality.
For more details, you could refer to the link: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/

There are scenarios where you’ll want control over how Windows DPI
scales dialogs or even children HWNDs of a dialog. When you want to
opt a dialog or an HWND in a dialog out of automatic DPI scaling you
can use SetDialogDpiChangeBehavior/SetDialogControlDpiChangeBehavior,
respectively.


Temporarily solved by disabling the whole dpiScaling... too many issues

your answer is right, but dpiScaling has still many graphical issues so I disabled it, waiting for full implementation of DPI awareness

could you please upvote my question? stackoverflow is locking me from posting other questions :-( thanks!
